# Can a group be a union of finitely many subgroups of infinite index?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Is there a group $G$ and subgroups $H_1, \dots, H_n \leq G$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $[G : H_i] = \infty$ for each $1 \leq i \leq n$, and $$G = \bigcup_{i=1}^n H_i \ \ ?$$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It may well be a lot easier than this, but it follows from the answer to the weaker question [Can a group be a finite union of (left) cosets of infinite-index subgroups?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17396/can-a-group-be-a-finite-union-of-left-cosets-of-infinite-index-subgroups?rq=1) that it's not possible.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: More precisely, the claim follows from Lemma 4.2 of Newman's paper in http://math.uga.edu/~pete/Neumann54.pdf , which has a half-page proof (basically by induction on the number of distinct subgroups, the right-cosets of which one is trying to use to cover the whole group).